# Proving that $ω_1$ is locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals

I'm trying to show that $ω_1$ is locally compact, but when doing so, I need to show something else, which got me a bit stuck on.

I'm taking a $\alpha\in ω_1$, so $\{\alpha\}$ is an open set. Since $ω_1$ is Hausdorff, the closure of $\{ \alpha \}$ is $\{ \alpha \}$ itself. Now I want to show that $\{ \alpha \}$ is compact, and this is where I got stuck - I want to show that for every cover of $\{ \alpha \}$ I can find a finite sub-cover, but I don't see how to prove this, what made me wonder if I'm not trying to prove something which is false?

Comment: Not all $\alpha \in \omega_1$ are isolated points! Only successor ordinals (and $0$). I guess you're going on from [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966673/a-few-questions-on-omega-1/966692)? By the way, all singletons are compact, can you see why?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi

Where did I state that every $\alpha\in\omega_1$ is an isolated point? And all singletons being compact is exactly what I'm trying to prove, and unfortunately not sure on how. If I take the most simple cover of $\{ \alpha \}$ so it's $\{ \alpha \}$ itself, obviously a finite cover. But given any other cover, I'm not sure how to take a finite sub-cover out of it.

Comment: You wrote "I'm taking $\alpha \in \omega_1$, so $\{\alpha\}$ is an open set". A singleton being open is the definition of an isolated point. Now if $\{U_k\}_k$ is an open cover of $\{x\}$, then $x \in U_i$ for some $i$... can you extract a finite subcover of $\{U_k\}$ now?

Comment: Meaning every open cover of $\{ x \}$ is actually $\{ x \}$ itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prove that the space $\omega_1$ is locally compact, you have to prove that every point in $\omega_1$ has a compact **neighborhood**. If $\alpha\in\omega_1$ then the one-point set $\{\alpha\}$ is obviously compact, but it is not necessarily a neighborhood of $\alpha$; namely, it's not a neighborhood if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, such as $\omega$.

**Hint:** Prove that for each ordinal $\alpha$ the closed interval $[0,\alpha]=\{\xi:\xi\le\alpha\}$ is a compact neighborhood of $\alpha$.

**More hints:** Either $[0,\alpha]$ is always compact, or else there is a least counterexample. Suppose $\alpha$ is the least ordinal for which $[0,\alpha]$ is not compact, and let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $[0,\alpha]$ with no finite subcover. Choose $U\in\mathcal U$ so that $\alpha\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is an ordinal $\beta\lt\alpha$ such that $(\beta,\alpha]\subseteq U$. Now $[0,\beta]$ is compact and

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: But how do I know I can take a finite sub-cover of $[0,\alpha]$?  for example given the cover $\{ \{0\}, \,\{1\}, \,\{2\}, \,\{3\}, \,... \}$ of $[0,\omega]$, how can I take a finite sub-cover of this?

Comment: The right endpoint $\omega$ is an element of the closed interval $[0,\omega]=\{\xi:\xi\le\omega\}$. If you have an open cover of $[0,\omega]$, then some member $U$ of your cover must cover the point $\omega$. Since $U$ is a **open** set, it must contain some neighborhood $(n,\omega]$ of the point $\omega$. Now, to get a finite subcover, we only have to worry about covering the points $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: On the $\omega$ case it's ok, but more generally - for a limit $\alpha$,  we know $U$ must contain an open set $(\beta,\alpha]$. If $\beta$ is not limit, it's obvious. But what if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal? We'll have to repeat this process over and over again. How do we know we'll repeat it a finite number of times?

Comment: "How do we know we'll repeat it a finite number of times?" We use one of the most basic properties of $\omega_1$, the fact that it is well-ordered.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see how $\omega_1$ being well-ordered makes any difference. What I mean is that, given a cover $\{U_i \}_{i\in I}$ of $[0,\alpha]$, we know there is a $U_0$ (where $0\in I$) such that $U_0 = (\beta, \alpha]$, but what if $\beta$ is limit also? so we know there is a $U_1$ such that $U_1 = (\gamma, \beta]$. There is an infinite number of limit ordinals. What assures us this "process" will come to an end? Obviously, $0$ is the smallest, but my intention is we may get stuck on a loop like this before we reach $0$.

Comment: The ordinals you're talking about are **getting smaller** every time: $\alpha\gt\beta\gt\gamma$. Because the ordinals are well-ordered, you can't have a strictly decreasing infinite sequence of ordinals.

Comment: now that I got it, it looks so simple, thanks!:)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on a right way, and in your proof you can use the fact that there is no infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals.

Answer (score -1):

Every cover of $\{ a \}$ is actually $\{ a \}$ itself, so you can obviously take a finite sub-cover, which is simply $\{ a \}$! Thus, making $\omega_1$ locally compact.

Comment: Wow, that argument proves that **every** topological space is locally compact!